# Codename One: Uncentered Buttonnames and Validator bug?

Tags: codenameone

I have a Problem with longer Names in my Buttons. I made the Text of buttons centered in the designer but it seems there are Problems with longer names. Here is a screenshot:

[image: This is not centered]

Second thing is about the Validator. I have equal Validators on a new and edit Form. The new form is perfectly, but when the user wants to edit, the TextFields are filled already with his former input, though, the Validator says that the user has to add something to the required TextField, only when the user taps the TextField and untaps it again, the Validator accepts the values. Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did you center the text? Did you use a UIID with center alignment?

Comment: Yes, I unchecked the dervied Box and set it to center alignment.

Comment: Did you do that in all the styles (unselected, selected, pressed, disabled)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `setText()` after setting the validator it might not be triggered. You should install the validator after setting the text.